# how to implement Serializable on a class that is implementing Iterable

Tags: java

I have been trying to serialize this iterable java class for subsequent deployment.
Including the **Serializable** tag in the class below results to a java error. The code is a  generic multi-set(bag) implementation that uses linked-list data structure and implements iterator utilities for easy generic item iteration within the multi-set.
Anyone who can sprinkle some coding pixie dust and save the situation? Help Java-beans make a quintessential documentation!!

```
/**my iterable class **
**/

public class Bagged<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

private int n;
private Node first;

//create empty bag
public Bagged(){ first= null; n= 0; }

//check if bag is empty
public boolean empty(){return first==null;}
//add item
public void add(Item item){
    Node theold = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item= item;
    first.nextnode = theold;
    n++;
}
//return the number of items
public int size(){return n;}

//create linked list class as a helper
private class Node{private Item item;  private Node nextnode; }

//returns an iterator that iterates over all items in thine bag
public Iterator<Item> iterator(){
 return new ListIterator();
} 

//iterator class--> remove() function ommited typical of a bag implementation.
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item>
    {
     private Node current = first;
     public void remove(){ throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
     public boolean hasNext(){return current!=null;}
     public Item next() 
             {
        if(!hasNext())throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Item item = current.item;
            current = current.nextnode;
        return item;
             }
}
//main class omitted- end of iterable class.
}
```

Comment: @ankit-rustagi You definitely can implements multiple interfaces in Java

Answer (score 1):

Post the exact error, but if you only made Bagged Serializable the error is pretty clear:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Bagged<Object> bag = new Bagged<Object>();
  bag.add(new Object());
  new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()).writeObject(bag);
}

Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: Bagged$Node
```

The ListIterator class does not have to be Serializable since the Bagged class does not hold references to it. Note that you also will get this exception if the objects in the bag are not Serializable. To enforce that you would need declare Bagged as follows:

```
public class Bagged <Item extends Serializable> implements Iterable <Item>, Serializable
```

Comment: i get the java.io.NotSerializableException error even after adding the enhancement. Now that the list iterator cannot be serialized, how do i make an object reference to it so as to make it Serializable?

Comment: What error do you get -exactly-? What do you think it means? You do not need to make the iterator serializable because you should not want to save it typically.

Comment: ok dad!! i wont make the iterator to be serializable. I thought it could work but i know after this class' deployment on the client-side, the java runtime environment will take care of the iterator class within the serializable class.  I have found solace in ignoring errors. just like cheating the JVM on creation of generic arrays which is disallowed in java. Tricking JVM is a hobby. Thanx Walter. Feel free to chip in.